# Scheme, what is the difference in the call stack

Tags: scheme, callstack

```
(define d
  (append '(a) (call/cc
          (lambda (k) (k (append '(b) '(c)))))))

(define e
  (append '(a) (append '(b) '(c))))
```

What is the difference in the call stack between d and e?

Comment: As the first can be reduced to the second, they are the same. The reduction is `(call/cc (lambda (k) (k v)))` => `v`.

Comment: At what point do you want to examine the call stack? The call stacks during execution of these two functions will be different at certain points.

Comment: Since you are using `call/cc` you need to use the term call *tree* rather than call stack. :-)

Comment: So what are the advantages/disadvantages of using either or then? What is the difference in the tree? Just that one more branch is made in the first other than the second?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot one:

```
(define d
  (append '(a) (call/cc
          (lambda (k) (append '(b) '(c))))))
```

Your examples and the one above shows variations of the same code. A Compiler would reduce those to the exact same expressions.

As with eval, you shouldn't use call/cc if you can avoid it. Imagine that you are taking one of those lists as input from the user:

Imagine this example:

```
(define d
    (call/cc
         (lambda (abort) 
              (append    '(a) 
                         '(b) 
                         (let ((c (read))) 
                            (if (list? c) 
                                       c 
                                       (abort #f)))))))
```

Here if you input a list d will become '(a b ...), but if you don't supply it with a list (eg. you write 5) it will use the continuation (abort) to return #f instead of letting append do it's thing. This example could be written without call/cc (by doing read and if part first, but in some circumstances the alternative to a continuation is to complete a calculation that you half way know is going to be trown away.

call/cc is like a goto in other languages and can be used to make exceptions, cooperative multitasking, iterations, ++. See [Matt Might's Continuations by example](http://matt.might.net/articles/programming-with-continuations--exceptions-backtracking-search-threads-generators-coroutines/)